# Why centripetal force does not increase the value of tangential velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, vectors, coordinate-systems, centripetal-force

[image]

I found in a text book that the value does not change because the centripetal force is perpendicular to the tangential velocity.

But I am confused, because a vector can have a component, which is perpendicular to the vector.
So if the centripetal force is perpendicular to the tangential velocity, the component of the centripetal force which
is perpendicular to the centripetal force and
*parallel* to the tangential velocity is reasonable.so according to that centripetal force can increase the value of tangential velocity.I need help.I have searched everywhere but have not got the answer.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the sentence "*...the component of the centripetal force which is PARALLEL to the centripetal force is...*". Did you mean "tangential velocity" instead? Also, it is not clear what the image shows. Could you make it clearer or write what the different symbols are?

Comment: yes that is tangential force

Comment: What is the grey line and the angle B?  Are they and the equations in the figure part of your question?  If so, are they part of your confusion?  If not, I suggest you remove them from the diagram.

Comment: A vector *cannot* have a component perpendicular to itself.

Answer (score 3):

- **Centripetal force** is the name of the force that *points towards the centre.* This is in the *radial* direction.
- **Tangential velocity** is, as the name suggests, a velocity direction *tangent* to the circle.

The radial and tangential directions are by definition *always* perpendicular - in the same way that the x and y axes are.

You are of course right that if any parallel component exists then the tangential velocity *will* change. But this is just never the case with centripetal acceleration. If it *was* the case, then we *wouldn't have called it* centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP has made a mistake in applying second law of Newton. The law (about a particle) says:
$$\Sigma \vec F=m\vec a$$
As it is seen, this is a vector equation. This means that corresponding components of both side of the equation must be equal. Although it is not said in the law's body, but it is obvious that we must write the equation above with respect to the **same** coordinate system. We cannot write left side of the equation by using a coordinate system and the right side of the equation by using another coordinate system.

As it is seen, the OP has used a non-orthogonal coordinate system for expression (resolution) of the force $\vec R$.
[image]
$$P=R\tan\beta$$
But I think for expression of the acceleration and velocity, the OP has used common orthogonal coordinate system because it has been mentioned that tangential velocity is perpendicular to the centripetal force. And this is where mistake has been made.

It is correct to say the velocity will have a component parallel to the force $\vec P$, but this component of the velocity isn't the common tangential velocity that we know (and probably the OP refers to).

Comment: but sometimes we use that non-orthogonal coordinate system in many problems like Riverboat problem perticulerly "To cross the river by the shortest path"when the components are 120 degree to each other

Comment: @Neyamul I didn't say that you cannot use non-orthogonal coordinate system. I said the tangential velocity you mentioned in the question body isn't the same thing that we usually know. You can see in the last paragraph of my answer that I have said it is OK to say velocity has a component parallel to $\vec P$. But I think this question mostly related to terminology. Because when you say velocity, all think that you are referring to the common velocity that they know.

Comment: English Lesson : Instead of "breaking" I think the word you need is "resolving". You "resolve" a vector into its components.

Comment: Resolving = verb.  Resolution (the result of resolving) = noun.  Expression = noun, so this should be replaced by Resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is as follows:

**Why centripetal force does not increase the value of tangential velocity?**

Answer:

Assume you have circular motion as in the case where a person, with her hand, twirls a ball on a string. The string connects her fingers to the ball as the ball travels in a circle around her hand.

In this case, the force in the string is perpendicular to the velocity vector of the ball. Therefore, the force in the string **has no vector component that is in the direction of the ball's velocity vector**.

Since there is no force acting on the ball in the direction of its velocity vector, the ball's **speed** remains constant.

**DO NOT** confuse velocity with speed! In this case, the ball's speed is constant, however its velocity is always changing because the ball's direction of motion is ALWAYS changing. So, even though the ball is travelling at a constant SPEED, it is still accelerating because its direction of motion is always changing. Circular motion is a very tricky case of force, mass, velocity, speed, and acceleration.